# Citations and references appearing as text instead of numbers

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

I have been using TexLink with TexEditor. I am using DocumentClass elsarticle.

I have used the following snippet of code in my .bib file

```
@ONLINE {demand,
    key ="",
    year  = "",
   Howpublished= {\url},
   note={Retreived 2016-01-24}
   }
```

I ran the .tex file once, the .aux file associated with it once and the .tex file twice. But I am getting the references formatted as :

[image]

Instead I need them numbered as [3], [4]. The first two references are added correctly. I tried running the program several times but there was no change. The bibliography commands from my .tex document as below.

```
\begingroup
\raggedright
\bibliography{reference_PowerInterruption.bib}{21}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
\endgroup
```

Minimal working example added.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{times}%Use Times New Roman Font
\usepackage{url} %To recognize URLs
\begin{document}
\title{Integrated Model for Power Interruption Contracts}
\author{Lakshmi Palaparambil Dinesh}
\begingroup
\raggedright
\bibliography{reference_PowerInterruption.bib}{21}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  Can you try adding `number` to the options of `\documentclass{elsarticle}` i.e. `\documentclass[number]{elsarticle}`.

Comment: @Dai , thanks a lot for your help. I tried adding number, but no change. I have added MWE in the question.

Comment: Or replacing `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` with `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}`?

Comment: @Dai. Perfect. Great help.

Answer (score 1):

The `apalike` bibliography style does not generate a numbered bibliography.  Using the `elsarticle-num` bibliography style suggested in the documentation for the [`elsarticle`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) class will instead generate a numeric bibliography style, likely in best keeping with the style desired by Elsevier.